# How to apply the change of a variable with Nativescript and Mapbox in Typescript

Tags: android, angular, typescript, nativescript, mapbox

I try to change the value of a variable and apply that change in the view.
When i press a marker i want  to show the infos in the same page in a 'div' who pass 'hidden' to 'visible'

I use a function that changes the value of the variable 'showInfo()'.
For the test, this function is called 2 actions.

- work: The first is to call with a button (see FRONT).
- don't work: The second is to call when I touch the marker (see BACK).

  ***********************FRONT HTML***********************

```
<FlexboxLayout  height="100%" width="100%" style="z-index: 1">
        <Mapbox
                accessToken="TOKEN"
                mapStyle="mapbox://styles/MAP"
                latitude="37.7397"
                longitude="-121.4252"
                hideCompass="true"
                zoomLevel="2"
                showUserLocation="true"
                disableZoom="false"
                disableRotation="false"
                disableScroll="false"
                disableTilt="false"
                (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)">
        </Mapbox>
        <Label text="{{infoText}}" width="10%" height="10%" backgroundColor="yellow"></Label>
</FlexboxLayout >

<FlexboxLayout  height="10%" width="80%" class="INFO" [ngStyle]="{'visibility': visibility , 'background-color': 'green', 'z-index': 2 }">
            <Label text="{{infoText }}" width="70%" height="70%" backgroundColor="yellow"></Label>
</FlexboxLayout >
```

************BACK**************************************

```
private map: MapboxViewApi;
visibility: string = 'hidden';
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
}


onMapReady(args): void {
    this.map = args.map;
    this.map.addMarkers([
        {
            lat: 37.7397,
            lng: -121.4252,
            title: 'Tracy, CA',
            subtitle: 'Home of The Polyglot Developer! HOHO',
            onTap: () => {
                this.showInfo();
            }
        }
    ]);
}

showInfo() {
    console.log(this.visibility);
    this.visibility = 'visible';
    console.log(this.visibility);
}
```

When I press the button, the label that is 'hidden' becomes 'visible'.
But when I press the marker, the function is launched (the value of the variable changes) but the label is still insensible.

Looks like changing the variable is not supported when i use the function 'onTap' of Mapbox.

Comment: I suspect `onTap` doesn't run inside NgZone, you might want to run it inside NgZone, something like `this._ngZone.run(() => { this. showInfo() });`. The constructor should inject zone `constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone) {}
`.

Comment: THANK YOU, it work !!!
I will look at ngzone more precisely.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect `onTap` callback is being executed outside NgZone, which is why your component is not detecting the changes. Try running your code inside [NgZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone)

```
constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone) {} 

onMapReady(args): void {
    this.map = args.map;
    this.map.addMarkers([
        {
            lat: 37.7397,
            lng: -121.4252,
            title: 'Tracy, CA',
            subtitle: 'Home of The Polyglot Developer! HOHO',
            onTap: () => {
                this._ngZone.run(() => { this. showInfo() });.
            }
        }
    ]);
}
```